# How to hide/show multiple objects in Jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to hide/show items and show them again if requested.

I am using the following code to do it. But it slows down the page if i do it few times.

```
for(i=0;i < 9; i++) 
  $('.myBetSingleBox').eq(i).css({'display':''});
```

Is there a way to do it without slowing down the page? the for loop is slowing down the page, but i dont have another solution.

maybe is there a Garbage Collection possible in JQuery?

**info:** 
**hide**(), **toggle**() methods are worst then css({'display':''});

Thanks!

Comment: *many times* - how many exactly?

Comment: Do you want to hide the first 10 elements or do you want to hide all children of .myBetSingleBox?

Comment: there are X childrens and i want to hide 9 of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will hide the first 9 elements with that class.

```
$('.myBetSingleBox:lt(8)').hide();
```

That situation you are describing (hiding 9 elements) as a bottleneck of your application sounds unlikely.

Comment: @VuralAcar: More of a feature than just a spontaneous idea. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In order to make things faster, you have to **cache** your DOM references:

```
var boxes = $('.myBetSingleBox');
```

Then just:

```
boxes.slice(0, 8).hide();
```

and

```
boxes.slice(0, 8).show();
```

The above lines should take less than 1 ms (milliseconds) to execute, so they can't be the reason for your performance issues...

Answer (score 0):

Make all of the elements you want to show children of a common element. Then, apply the css display property to that common element.